# How to design my ingredient database tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, primary-key

I'm working on an recipe module (ASP.NET MVC, entity framework, sql server), and one of the entities I have to setup in the database are ingredients, their characteristics and translations to a number of languages.

I was thinking of creating two tables as follows:

```
Table Ingredient
     Id, nvarchar(20), primary key
     EnergyInKCal, float
     ... other characteristics
     Source, nvarchar(50)

Table IngredientTranslation
     Id, nvarchar(20), primary key
     LanguageCode, nvarchar(2)
     Name, nvarchar(200)
```

So each ingredient will be defined once in the Ingredient table, with a unique code as their primary key, for example:

```
 'N32-004669', 64, 368, 'NUBEL'
```

and translated in the IngredientTranslation table, for example

```
 'N32-004669', 'NL', 'Aardappel, zoete' 
 'N32-004669', 'FR', 'Pomme de terre, douce' 
 'N32-004669', 'EN', 'Potatoe, sweet'
```

I think querying ingredients becomes easy like this... do you think it's a good idea to use code (which is nvarchar(20)) as a primary key? Or is a simple bigint better, but then I have to use JOINS in my queries. Maybe other approaches that are better - performance wise?

EDIT: after reading the answers, I redesigned the tables as follows:

```
Table Ingredient
     Id, bigint, primary key
     ExternalId, nvarchar(20)
     EnergyInKCal, float
     ... other characteristics
     Source, nvarchar(50)

Table IngredientTranslation
     Id, bigint, primary key
     IngredientId, bigint (relation with Id of Ingredient table)
     LanguageCode, nvarchar(2)
     Name, nvarchar(200)
```

Thanks,
L

Comment: So, how do you think you are going to avoid JOINs by using `nvarchar`s?

Comment: well, because with each recipe I store the code, so if I want to retrieve the characteristics and name, i can use just 'code' (and language) to query?

Comment: So you are thinking of making an extra query? 1. There is nothing about integer ids that makes them less suitable than nvarchars for querying the database. 2. OFG NOOO! *don't make an extra query, it is MUCH faster to use a join!*

Comment: Ok, can you check the EDITED part of my question, do you think it's ok this way?

Comment: Yes, much better now. But as others have said, the primary key on IngredientTranslation must be BOTH Id and LanguageCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a primary key is included in every other index, it's best to keep the primary key small.  So an `int identity` is an excellent choice.

One side note: storing translations in a database has a rather hefty performance impact.  Both on the database and the rendering engine that has to build the web page.  Since translations are fairly constant, most websites store them outside the database.  In ASP.NET, the typical choice would be resource files.

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying that I should add an Id (bigint) as primary key instead of the varchar ones, and use JOINS in my queries? Concerning resource files: as it would be possible for the user to define custom ingredients, a resource file is probably not very flexible...

Comment: Also, see my EDIT for additional question

Comment: Yes.  One query with a join is typically much faster than multiple separate queries.  RE edit: yeah, a surrogate key is added to the column list, it does not replace the varchar id.

Comment: But if you choose surrogate key, then the (Unique) `Code` stays in the `Ingredients` table only. You remove it from the `IngredientTranslation` table.

Comment: @ypercube: Good point, but how would the website know the `Code` to start with?  It probably retrieves it from the database, and then it can ask for the surrogate key or the translation in the same query.

Comment: Sure, though an [integer would probably do fine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198(v=sql.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In a purely relational schema, using a natural key (such as ID, above) as the primary key should be fine, although in OO design surrogate keys are likely to be preferred.

A couple of additonal notes:

- The primary key on IngredientTranslation would need to be a compound key on ID and Language Code, not just ID.
- From First Normal Form: remove derived values. So you only need one field for Energy - pick one of the energy units (kJ or kCal) and use the appropriate multiplication factor to convert where appropriate.

EDIT: in the alternative scenario, I suggest adding a unique index to each of the Ingredient (on code) and IngredientTranslation (on Code and Language Code) tables. I also suggest renaming the code field as IngredientCode on the IngredientTranslation table.

Comment: indeed, in the translations table it would be a compound key. You second remark is of course valid, my example was not correct. I won't put redundant data in there...

Comment: Also, see my EDIT for additional question